# is it possible to set permission in zend acl to action level insted of controller level

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation, zend-acl, php

i am using zend framework , in my site i have two types of users , guest and loggeduser , i have a controller called . books , in there i have 3 actions . add , edit and delete ,

in my zend acl i give the permissions to books controller only to logged user , in my navigation , books link is not shown to the guest , instead of that i want to show all 3 sublinks to logged user and , only add sub link to guest

like this

to loged user

- books

  - add
  - edit
  - delete

and to guest

- books

  - add

the problem is when i set permissions in acl , the books link is completely not showing to the guest ,

this part of my acl

```
    $this->addResource(new Zend_Acl_Resource('books'));
    $this->addResource(new Zend_Acl_Resource('login'));
    $this->addResource(new Zend_Acl_Resource('logout'));        

    $this->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('guest'));
    $this->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('user'), 'guest');

    $this->allow('guest', 'login');
$this->allow('user','logout');
    $this->allow('user','books');

$this->deny('guest', 'logout');
$this->deny('user', 'login');
```

is there any way to set permission to action level or i need a plugin . 
i tried so hard to find a solution for hours , but couldn't .
please help ............... thanks  :(

UPDATE .

don't get confuced by the name , this is not the default zend Acl.php . this is a custom one stays in my models folder

part of my navigation.xml

```
<configdata>
    <nav>
        <books>
           <label>Books</label>
           <controller>books</controller>
           <action>index</action>
           <resource>books</resource>
           <pages>
                    <add>
                        <label>Add</label>
                        <controller>books</controller>
                        <action>add</action>
                    </add>
                    <edit>
                        <label>Edit</label>
                        <controller>books</controller>
                        <action>edit</action>
                    </edit>
                    <delete>
                        <label>Delete</label>
                        <controller>books</controller>
                        <action>delete</action>
                    </delete>
          </pages>
       </books>
   </nav>
</configdata>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted already, you will have to add privileges to the resource. `$this->allow('role','resource',array('privilege'));` Many people use the `controller` as the resource and `action` as the privilege.

I am assuming you are using `Zend_Navigation` in combination with `Zend_Acl` to show the proper navigation to signed on users. The simple reason why `books` and it's `pages` are not showing is because you did not give `guest` permission to see the parent `books`. You will have to allow `guest` access to the same resource and privilege defined for `books`. So, you will have to do something like the following:

```
$this->allow('guest', 'books', array('index', 'add')
```

Then, you can give `user` access:

```
$this->allow('user', 'books', array('edit','delete')); // index & add are inherited
```

Now, in your `Zend_Navigation_Page` you will have to set the resource as `books` and the privilege to `index`.

Comment: i add it like that , but now the books link is completly not showing to either , guest or logged in user

Comment: Can you update your question with how your adding the books page to your navigation? I suspect that you have `'resource'=>'books'` and missing `'privilege'='index'`

Comment: hei i added part of my navigation.xml .please check it

Comment: Add `<privilege>index</privilege>` under `<resource>books</resource>`, that should do the trick

Comment: yep . this works now , but i had to add resource and privilege under each action . thanks  lot :D

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->deny($this->editor,'artist',array('delete'));
```

where artist is the resource (controller) and delete is the action.

see http://zendguru.wordpress.com/2008/11/05/zend-framework-acl-with-example/ for an example.

and/or http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.refining.html#zend.acl.refining.precise